# How to decrease the number of issues?

Tags: numbers, sonarqube, false-positive

When I mark as false positive or resolved some issues, the total number of issues is not decremented. Is that behavior normal? If so, is there a way to decrease this number according to the number of marked issues?

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.4 (LTS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is normal.

When you resolve (mark False Positive, Won't Fix, or Fixed) an issue the numbers in your dashboard won't reflect that resolution until after the next analysis. That's because those dashboard numbers are *Metrics*, and metrics aren't updated on the fly - only during analysis.

However, you should see the counts on the Issues page update immediately. Those numbers *are* calculated on the fly based on the issue set that matches the current query.

Comment: Hi G. Ann, thanks for your answer. I didn't realize the next analysis takes into account the resolved issues of the previous one. That seems to suit our needs, that is to "hide" temporarily some issues. Having the right number in the dashboard allow us to view the time changes based on it.